# How to convert array elements to integer in Python

Tags: python, arrays, rsa

I am trying to implement **rsa** algorithm. So, I would like to combine array elements based on block size. For example:

```
blockSize = 2
arr = [1, 3, 45, 6, 2, 90, 103]
```

I am willing to merge the elements in a way that 1st and 2nd will be combined into one element. so the array would look like this:

```
arr = [13, 456, 290, 103]
```

Comment: did you try something? What did not work?

Comment: Look at the highest voted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks). From that solution, change the yield part to yield this instead: `int(''.join(map(str, l[i:i + n])))`

Comment: Look at `int.from_bytes()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide to chunks by `block_size`, then map all the values in each cell to `string`s, the join the strings and convert them to `integer`:

```
new_arr = [int(''.join(map(str, arr[i: i+block_size]))) for i in range(0, len(arr), block_size)]
```

More detailed overview on the chunks convertion:

```
int(''.join(map(str, arr[i: i+block_size])))
                     arr[i: i+block_size]      for every chunk
            map(str, ....................)     map every number in the chunks to string
    ''.join(..............................)    join these strings
int(.......................................)   convert the join string to integer
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked for me. but i interpreted it in another way. like this:


`for index in range(0, len(arr), bs):
    new = ''.join( map ( str, arr[index : index + bs] ) )
 `